# How to use mail() function in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I am working on an existing Laravel 5.4 project hosted on AWS. It consists code to send email using Laravel's `Mail` facade and `MailMessage` feature for notification emails. But, in some places I observe usage of `mail()` function from PHP. These lines of code using `mail()` function don't seem to work anywhere and I have been unable to understand why it isn't working when there's no error and it apparently should work properly. However, mails are being sent using Laravel's `Mail` facade without any error.

I used MailTrap to test sending emails and I encountered no problem doing that. But, for production code I want to be able to use `mail()` function because using other services is currently out of question. I have looked into Amazon SES and SparkPost which currently seem the best option if `mail()` doesn't work. 
MailGun might also be relevant as the system won't be sending more than 10k emails per month which are included in MailGun's free tier. The project itself is hosted on AWS.

I want to be able to use `mail` or `sendmail` driver and not `smtp`.

This is my code currently.

**.env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Values in `mail.php` point to `.env` variables.

For Mailtrap testing, I of course used `smtp` with the following configuration:

**.env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=<MAILTRAP_USERNAME>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<MAILTRAP_PASSWORD>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Allegedly Faulty `mail()` code:

```
mail("user@example.com","Exception in Controller->somefunction : " . get_class($e), $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . $e->getTraceAsString());

mail("user@example.com","Test Subject","Some Content","From: user@mydomain.com" );
```

So, how can I use PHP's `mail()` function in Laravel 5.4 ?

All other answers on so many similar questions include information on changing to `smtp`,to use MailGun/MailTrap/SendGrid etc but no one offers explanation on how to make it work with `mail` driver, which is something I'm specifically looking for, at least to understand why it would not work as it was not deprecated in Laravel 5.4 version.

Comment: In `laravel` you don't need to use the native `mail` function at all there is a `mail` class  in `laravel` you can check it https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail

Comment: Yes, I'm aware.All that requires `smtp` but I'm looking to make it work with `mail` driver. I am actually refactoring the existing code to use `Mail` facade everywhere, but I'm flustered as to why the existing code wouldn't work. `Laravel` supports the `mail` driver as per the documentation.

Comment: check this part it talk about sending it https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#sending-mail

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm refactoring the code to. It exists in most of the files but in some places `mail()` is used specifically(to send emails to admin about caught exceptions). Please re-read and understand the question.

Comment: then I suppose you should check how to use the native mail function in the PHP docs. Probably you would need to update some settings in your php.ini or something.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

Comment: I just checked my configuration files. Everything seems fine there. php.ini file has the correct values as mentioned.

Comment: What error do you get, and also did you restart your apache or nginx server? can you run `php -i | grep "smtp"` in your command line if you are using ssh or something? maybe the server uses another php.ini file?

Comment: Thats the problem. I don't get any error. I just don't see any emails received where it should be. 
I also ran the above mentioned command. It gives out to me the smtp_port values. So, I guess its fine, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200672/discussion-between-kanwarbir-singh-and-taha-paksu).

Answer (score 0):

**The issue was solved.** The problem had more to do with AWS than Laravel. This is what I had to do:

1.) I just had to verify my domain name in Amazon SES settings. Learn more about this here: 
[Verifying email addresses in Amazon SES.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses.html)

2.) Just to be safe, I refactored the code to replace all mentions of PHP's `mail()` function with Laravel's `Mail` facade. The reason for this was because I was unable to send emails as they would get stuck on the server mailbox after not being able to go through AWS due to the whole verification of domain thing. Apparently, Laravel's `Mail` uses the `mail` driver a bit differently than PHP's `mail()` function. My settings in code are mentioned below:

A lot of my code remained the same as mentioned in the question.

**.env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

**\config\mail.php**

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mail'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => ['address' => "<user>@<domainname>.com", 'name' => null],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

So, you can see I didn't even have to use `SES` driver from Laravel. Because, my project uses AWS hosting, I guess I just had to verify my domain name in the SES settings and Laravel `Mail` facade does the rest.

- I did not have to fall back to SMTP settings as so many other answers
  related to this issue mentioned on SO.
- I did not even have to change my mail settings.

One takeaway is that you need to make sure that you use Laravel's `Mail` or `MailMessage` feature to build and send all your emails in the project.